# Biased Random w/ MongoDB and Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Currently I am making a system where users submit images, they get put into a database by the use of a Schema and then users can use a command (through discord/discordjs) to pull a random biased/weighted image (and therefore document) from mongoDB and have it sent to them with options to vote on the image or report it.

**That is the idea ^, Here is where I am so far:**

.

Users can Submit images using a command through discord and it works.

The MongoDB document is made with these values:

```
const imageSchema = new Schema({
imageId: { type: Number, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
imageLocation: reqString,
votes: {type: Number, required: false, default: 0},
verified: {type: Number, required: false, default: 0},})
```

[Image of what it looks like in mongodb compass for more context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23cun.png)

What I am completely stumped on is how to scan all the documents and create a way to pick out one of the images randomly (not THE most highest voted, just have higher number of votes on a document make it show up more), that are most highly voted using JavaScript.

**Any suggestions on this would be great, code snippets explaining concepts would be good too.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation pipeline with the `$sample` operator.

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
imageSchema.aggregate([
  {
    $sample: {
      size: 1 // <- how many random documents you want
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I saw this in the documentation but it doesn't solve my issue (or at least I don't think it does) as I want the random document it selects to be biased towards documents with a higher 'votes' value. So documents with 0 votes would appear less than documents with 100 votes for example.

EDIT: This might work if I could then make a way to take the random documents and then do the biased random within javascript, although I wouldnt know where to start with making this work.

Comment: If you want certain results to appear less than others than it is not a random document. You will need to define those constraints somehow. It sounds like you want higher votes to hold more weight, but only you can determine the weight. You will basically need to decide if you want greater than N votes to hold X% weight, etc...